# Typo3 - ReDirect and RouteEnhancer

Tags: typo3

I am having trouble with my Extbase-Plugin, redirects and route enhancers:

I have a plugin that gets job offers via an API and displays as a list on a Typo3-page. I have written a route enhancer to make the URLs for the single job offers pretty.

If a user clicks on a link, the method "showJob" from the controller is called. This method redirects the user to a different page (I do need two distinct pages for this) and calls the method "showSingleJob".

I have written this redirect like this:

```
{
    $currentPid = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id;
    $jobID = $this->request->getArgument('jobID');
    $jobTitle = $this->request->getArgument('jobTitle');
    $pageID = $this->request->getArgument('pageID');


    $args = [
        'jobID' => $jobID,
        'jobTitle' => $jobTitle,
        "pageID" => $pageID
    ];

    $response = json_decode($this->curl_get_contents('https://api.jobsAPI.com/job/' . $jobID));

    if ($pageID != $currentPid) {


        $uriBuilder = $this->uriBuilder;
        $uri = $uriBuilder
            ->reset()
            ->setTargetPageUid(intval($pageID))
            ->setAddQueryString(TRUE)
            ->uriFor('showSingleJob', $args, 'UmJobs', 'UmJobs', 'jobliste');
        $this->redirectToUri($uri, 0, 404);
    }



    $this->view->assign('apiJob', $response);

}
```

The method "showSingleJob" simply gets the data for the desired job and displays it. This works just fine.

But I need pretty urls for the redirected page. At the moment I get my typo3-Url plus all the parameters I am passing. So I tried my hand at a route enhancer:

```
routeEnhancers:
  UmJobs:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 1
      - 3
    extension: UmJobs
    plugin: jobliste
    routes:
      - routePath: '/karriere/'
        _controller: 'UmJobs::list'

      - routePath: '/karriere/{jobTitle}/{jobID}/{pageID}'
        _controller: 'UmJobs::showJob'
        _arguments:
          jobTitle: jobTitle
          jobID: jobID
          pageID: pageID
          defaultController: 'UmJobs::showJob'

      - routePath: '/karriere/job/{jobTitle}/{jobID}/{pageID}'
        _controller: 'UmJobs::showSingleJob'
        _arguments:
          jobTitle: jobTitle
          jobID: jobID
          pageID: pageID
          defaultController: 'UmJobs::showSingleJob'

    requirements:
      jobID: '^[0-9].*$'
      pageID: '^[0-9].*$'
      jobTitle: '^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$'
```

Again this works fine for "showJobs" but It doens't work at all for "showSingleJobs". It seems as if the enhancer is completely ingored by $uribuilder.

Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me as if your URIs are *not* unique...

### 'UmJobs::showJob

```
routePath: '/karriere/{jobTitle}/{jobID}/{pageID}'
```

Now lets the values be:

```
jobTitle = job  // Matching the requirement '^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$'
jobID = 123     // Matching the requirement '^[0-9].*$'
pageID = 987    // Matching the requirement '^[0-9].*$'
```

The path would be: `/karriere/job/123/987`

### 'UmJobs::showSingleJob

```
routePath: '/karriere/job/{jobTitle}/{jobID}/{pageID}'
```

Now lets the values be:

```
jobTitle = 123  // Matching the requirement '^[a-zA-Z0-9].*$'
jobID = 987     // Matching the requirement '^[0-9].*$'
pageID = ''     // Matching the requirement '^[0-9].*$'
```

The path would be: `/karriere/job/123/987`

### Conclusion

You can have the *same* URI for *different* actions - which can not be served.

Comment: IMO the routePaths are evaluated from top to bottom. So if you start with the most specific path then it might work.

Comment: While there are no jobs with the same name and ID, I entertained your thought and made UmJobs::showSingleJob unique by adding another string => karriere/job/test/123/987. Also I tried rearranging the roue enhancers, but without any success. The thing is, the page is reachable under the pretty url - it just doesn't show up in the browser's address bar...